# Show push message in chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I want to show push notification using a service worker. In the developer tools -> Application -> Service workers I have the test text `"a": "test message"`, I press the push and get the following error:

```
serviceWorker.js:48 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 
'showNotification' on 'ServiceWorkerRegistration': No notification 
permission has been granted for this origin.
```

How can I fix this? When you click on the push button, should the notification pop up?

Answer (score 5):

For Push messages, you need two API's setup **Notification API** and **Push API**. 
First things first, ask permission of the client for notification. Unless that is granted nothing works. So in your index.js/App.js place this snippet:-

```
function askForNPerm() {
  Notification.requestPermission(function(result) {
    console.log("User choice", result);
    if (result !== "granted") {
      console.log("No notification permission granted!");
    } else {
      configurePushSub();// Write your custom function that pushes your message
    }
  });
}
```

Once you are allowed with the permission, then call your Push function that has message to display.

Answer (score 0):

It's Work. You also need to check if your browser has permission.

```
 self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
    const options = {
        body: 'This notification was generated from a push!',
        icon: '',
        data: {
            dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
            primaryKey: '2'
        },
        actions: [
            {
                action: 'explore', title: 'Explore this new world',
                icon: ''
            },
            {
                action: 'close', title: 'Close',
                icon: ''
            },
        ]
    };
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification('Title', options)
    )
    });
```

Comment: You didn’t allow any permissions,